# Как мне удалить последнюю строку?

Tags: python

Текс может быть любой,
например:

```
Python — высокоуровневый язык программирования 
общего назначения с динамической строгой типизацией и автоматическим 
управлением памятью, ориентированный на повышение производительности разработчика, 
читаемости кода и его качества, 
а также на обеспечение переносимости написанных на нём программ.
```

Надо чтоб стало так:

```
Python — высокоуровневый язык программирования 
общего назначения с динамической строгой типизацией и автоматическим 
управлением памятью, ориентированный на повышение производительности разработчика, 
читаемости кода и его качества,
```

Думал сделать через срез, но не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Найдите индекс последнего символа переноса строки(`\n`) в тексте, и обрежьте исходный текст от нуля, до этого индекса

```
text = """Python — высокоуровневый язык программирования 
общего назначения с динамической строгой типизацией и автоматическим 
управлением памятью, ориентированный на повышение производительности разработчика, 
читаемости кода и его качества, 
а также на обеспечение переносимости написанных на нём программ."""

new_text = text[:text.rfind('\n')]
print(new_text)
```

Comment: спасибо, а как тогда вывести первую строку?

Comment: @Vlad аналогично ищите первый перенос строки методом find. Или же на список разбивайте текст, и по индексу выводите

Comment: а как мне вывести тут то что я удаляю:
```
new_text = text[:text.rfind('\n')]
```

Comment: @CameL на строке без символов '\n' будет работать неверно.

Answer (score 1):

можно так - разобрать на строку и собрать в строку:

```
new_text = '\n'.join(text.split('\n')[:-1])
```